# Animate jQuery UI dialog when content expands or contracts while staying centered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) dialog popup, and then inside are buttons to show/hide content. If one button is clicked, when the content expands, I simply call the following to recenter the dialog on the screen.

```
var position = $(selector).dialog( "option", "position" );
$(selector).dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );
```

I want it to animate when the dialog expands or contracts while staying centered within the browser. I have seen other overlay boxes do this, but I'm trying to get it to work with jQuery UI. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to animate the centering process? Or what kind of animation are you talking about?

Comment: Well for example lets say the viewport height is 1000px and I have a box that is 400px tall.  When a button is clicked, 200 more px of content appear, making the box 600px tall.  So I suppose what I want it to do is 'grow' from the top and bottom by 100px, thus keeping it centered.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to use `animate()` on the dialog to animate the new position. However, you would need to inspect how the line `$(selector).dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );` actually works so you can get figure out how to manually calculate the new position of the dialog (so it is centered).

Comment: yes... this is where I'm running into a wall.